# MySql updating column that is null

Tags: mysql

I was trying to update a column value that has a null value.

Table:

```
+------------+-----------+-------+
| product_no | name      | price |
+------------+-----------+-------+
|          1 | Cheese    |  9.99 |
|       NULL | Meat      | 17.00 |
|          2 | Pepperoni |  NULL |
+------------+-----------+-------+
```

Update:

```
UPDATE products SET product_no = 6 WHERE product_no = NULL;
```

Output:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Table definition:

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_no | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name       | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price      | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Why is this not updating to `6`?

Comment: Nothing is equal, nor not equal, to NULL - not even NULL! A value either IS or IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Ooh forgot about that.

Comment: `select null=null` gives a nice answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because NULL is special.

MySql [states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html):

> To test for NULL, use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators...
>
> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.

Hence:

```
UPDATE products SET product_no = 6 WHERE product_no IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE products SET product_no = 6 WHERE product_no is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL value is special, use:

```
WHERE product_no IS NULL
```

or

```
WHERE product_no <=> NULL
```